# Conditions about returning Chandra's Phoenix in one's hand

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent and I encountered a problem.

I had a [Volcanic Geyser](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Volcanic%20Geyser), which let me choose to deal damage to an opponent Creature, or the opponent Player.

I also had a [Chandra's Phoenix](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chandra%27s%20Phoenix) in my Graveyard, when I cast the Geyser on my opponent's Creature.

Now I am asking about the Phoenix's text. It says:

> Whenever an opponent is dealt damage by a red instant or sorcery spell you control or by a red planeswalker you control, return Chandra's Phoenix from your graveyard to your hand.

Does it mattere if I deal the damage to a opponent ***player*** or an opponent ***creature?*** Can I choose which one I deal damage to, and still fulfill the conditions to return the Phoenix in my hand?

Answer (score 6):

*Opponent* only refers to players, not creatures. Chandra's Phoenix will not trigger if you target a creature.

Comprehensive Rules reference:

> 102.2. In a two-player game, a player’s *opponent* is the other player.
>
> 102.3. In a multiplayer game between teams, a player’s *teammates* are the other players on his or her team, and the player’s opponents are all players not on his or her team.

Answer (score 3):

Chandra's Phoenix's ability triggers *whenever an **opponent** is dealt damage by ...*

> 102.2. In a two-player game, a player’s opponent is the other player.
>
> 102.3. In a multiplayer game between teams, a player’s teammates are the other players on his or her team, and the player’s opponents are all players not on his or her team.

You would have to target and deal damage to your opponent using Volcanic Geyser, not one of his creatures.

Answer (score 0):

Chandra's Phoenix won't trigger if you deal damage to an opponent's creature. You have to deal damage to the player himself.